# What WooCommerce hook would be used to wrap this code in a div?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Below is a snippet of code that is output on my WooCommerce Products Page that shows a list of products in columns. I want to wrap the code below in a  but don't know which named hook to use.

```
<li class="post-5908 product type-product status-publish has-post-thumbnail product_cat-lingerie post post-with-thumbnail post-with-thumbnail-large first instock product-type-simple">
    <a href="https://www.example.com/product/1260/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link">
     <div class="makebottom-wrap">
       <img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-300x200.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="My sample product" title="My sample product" srcset="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-300x200.jpg 300w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-150x100.jpg 150w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-768x512.jpg 768w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-1024x683.jpg 1024w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-600x400.jpg 600w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct-272x182.jpg 272w, https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/myproduct.jpg 1200w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" width="300" height="200">
     </div>
     <h3>1260</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What are you trying to achieve that cannot be achieved with the existing `<li>` list notation? And if you look at the [`content-product.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/2.6.13/templates/content-product.php) template, there does not appear to be a hook, therefore the best bet would be simply overriding that template.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li <?php post_class( $classes ); ?>>
<?php 
if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )){
 echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'shop_catalog');
}else{
 echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; 
}
?>

</li>
```